# Is there a way to make voice recognition multi-language?

Tags: voice-recognition, input-methods

I am German but my Android is in English for various reasons. However, I like using voice commands since it is the fastest way to get the music playing I like.

It recognizes most bands without any problem, but I cannot get it to recognize any German bands, e.g.:

```
Ok Google, play Unheilig Schutzengel
```

recognizes as

```
1 highlights
```

and results in a google search for this term. The only ones working are bands with Latin names like `In Extremo` or `Rammstein`.

Is there a way to solve this problem? Or is my accent not American/British enough for it recognize bands with German names?

Comment: Since your locale language is English, Google is deliberately not recognizimg German (probably thinking of it as some input error). If you chose German as a voice recognition language, it wouldn't recognize English. Somehow both don't work together. Blame Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google speech recognition software supports multi language input, so yes, you can easily solve the problem. Go to the app 'Google settings' -> Search & Now -> Voice -> Languages. Here check all the languages that you want Google to recognise. If you long press on a language it will be set as the primary: first Google tries to match your input with the primary language, then if it fails, it tries with the languages labelled as 'others'. You can either set German as primary or English, Google does recognise words from both languages in the same sentence.

Comment: Oh thank you, this worked. It now properly recognizes the song I used above as an example. Didn't notice this app for the google settings. Thanks a ton.